# What is the limit of this function as x approaches 2?

Tags: calculus, limits

I saw a video on Khanacademy where they said that given the following function:

$$F(x) = \begin{cases}x^2 & x \not = 2 \\ 1 &  x = 2 \end{cases}$$
the limit of the function when x approached 2 was equal to 4. Is that right? From what I learned we can approach a value either from the right or left and in this case it woud be 4 if x approached 2 from the left but not from the right so in general there wouldnt be a limit for when x approaches 2. Thanks.

Comment: Khan is right.  If you get closer and closer to x equals 2 from either side the y values that correspond will approach 4.

Comment: "from the left but not from the right": how so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true that
$$
\lim_{x \to 2} F(x) = 4.
$$
To see why, note that $F(x) = x^2$ whenever $x \neq 2$. That is, $F(x) = x^2$ for $x < 2$ and for $x > 2$. So, the left and right limits are given (respectively) by
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 2^-} F(x) = \lim_{\substack{x \to 2\\x < 2}} F(x)
=  \lim_{\substack{x \to 2\\x < 2}} x^2 = \lim_{x \to 2^-} x^2 = 4
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 2^+} F(x) = \lim_{\substack{x \to 2\\x > 2}} F(x)
=  \lim_{\substack{x \to 2\\x > 2}} x^2 = \lim_{x \to 2^+} x^2 = 4.
\end{align*}
Looking at the graph of $F(x)$ helps to understand why the right limit also behaves this way.

Comment: I guess what I missed was that there was also a parabola for values bigger than 2 because he didn't draw it in the video. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For $x$ in $(0,4)$, $$|x^2-4|=|x+2||x-2|<6|x-2|.$$

So by an $\epsilon,\delta$ argument, the limit is indeed $4$. The value of $F$ at $x=2$ plays no role.